# Axioms of Expectation Proof: Probability of Arbitrary Sets

Tags: probability, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, expectation

If A, B are arbitrary sets, use the five axioms of expectation to prove: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Any hints to go about this? I can prove the case where they are discrete sets, so it's more of the case where the sets are not exclusive.

1. $X \geq 0, then E(X) \geq 0$
2. $E(cX) = cE(X)$
3. $E(X_1 + X_2) = E(X_1) + E(X_2)$
4. $E(1) = 1$
5. If a sequence of random variables $X_i(w)$ is monotonically increasing to a limit $X(w)$, then $E(X_i)$ converges to $E(X)$.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\raise{0.5ex}\chi$ denote the indicator variable.

prove that

$$\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{A\cup B}+\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{A\cap B}=\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{A}+\raise{0.5ex}\chi_B$$

Comment: Why exactly are you transforming this case to an indicator variable in this case? And how do you use the axioms to prove this statement?

Comment: Expectation of indicator variable gives us probability.

Comment: Thanks. How would I write $\chi $ notation in terms of $I(A, \omega)$? From here, do I just give four cases for $\omega $? $\omega$ in both A, B, in A and not B, in B and not A, and not in A and B. And then, take the expectation of both sides?

Comment: $I(A,\omega ) =1$ if $\omega \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Your strategy seems fine.

Comment: $\raise{0.5ex}\chi_A(\omega) \equiv I(A, \omega)$